# Mocking moment format with timezone in jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, nestjs

I'm testing a service which formats a date based in a timezone, it's working perfectly, but when I'm running the tests, I'm receiving the error:
`moment_timezone_1.default(...).utcOffset(...).format is not a function`

I already tried to develop in different approaches which I saw in StackOverflow, but none of them worked, the error message changes (split is not a function, for example).

What can I do to properly mock the moment for my case or use the moment without mocking, but working, obviously?

Here is the function which gives an error:

```
export function formatTimezone(date, timezone = '+00:00', format = '') {
    return moment(date)
        .utcOffset(timezone)
        .format(format);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this: https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/mocking-moment-js-in-jest-a-simple-one-line-solution-61259ffaaa2

Comment: yes, when I do that the error changes: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/03-manipulating/09-utc-offset/) `utcOffset(timezone)` returns the offset (a number) when no argument is provided. It seems to also do this when `null` is provided - see below.

```js
console.log(moment().utcOffset(0).format())
console.log(moment().utcOffset(null).format())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

You need to validate the timezone input to make sure `utcOffset` isn't returning a number before calling `.format()` on it.

Comment: oh my...I was pointing in the wrong direction, the error was with this function! Thanks a lot, my friend.